# El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'WinForms' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'Microsoft.Reporting'

Tags: c#, reportviewer

[image: Esto me aparece, pero no me marca un error claro]

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecere muchooo

Comment: Saludos, debes colocar el código y no una foto del mismo. Te invito a que por favor leas sobre el [Codigo de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) y tambien sobre  [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias, lo haré

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes entrar a esta dirección aquí te dan una posible solución

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52ca4f7b-1249-42d7-96fe-48e87922564f/microsoftreportingwinformsreportviewer-is-not-defined-on-ms-build-server?forum=winformssetup

Cualquier cosa me dices espero te sirva

Básicamente la solución que plantea este enlace es borrar la referencia y volverla a añadir

Comment: gracias intentare a probarlo, espero que solucione mi problema.

Comment: me muestra ese error en varias lineas: que se compiló con la versión de .NET Framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6". Esta es una versión posterior a la versión de .NET Framework de destino actual ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2".